# Java NoClassDefFoundError, Not Sure What's Wrong

Tags: java

So I'm writing a Java program that calculates the difference between the sum of the squares of the first 100 integers and the square of the sum of the first 100 integers:

```
class project_euler6 {

    public static int sum_of_squares(int start, int end) {
        int total = 0;
        while (start <= end) {
            total += (start * start);
            start++;
        }
        return total;
    }

    public static int square_of_sums(int start, int end) {
        int total = 0;
        while (start <= end) {
            total += start;
            start++;
        }
        total *= total;
        return total;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int first_total = sum_of_squares(1, 100);
        int second_total = square_of_sums(1, 100);
        int difference = Math.abs(first_total - second_total);
        System.out.println("The difference between the sum of the squares and the square of the sums of first 100 integers is " + difference);
    }
}
```

When I run it, I get this strange error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: project_euler6/java
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: project_euler6.java
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Not sure where to start on this one...

Any help much appreciated,
Mariogs

Comment: Unfortunately, "NoClassDefFoundError" is Java's garbage exception -- about a dozen different errors rolled into one.  But in most cases the problem has something to do with mismatched jar files.

Comment: In this case, though, it appears to have something to do with this: project_euler6.java -- you're probably running `java project_euler6.java` rather than `java project_euler6`.

Comment: Edit your question and add the full command line you are using to start the app...

Comment: Can you please show how you call your program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with the code nor the access specifier with the class (`public` is not required before the class name). The actual problem is how are you executing it. I assume that you might have used `java project_euler6.java` instead of `java project_euler6`.

Answer (score 1):

For java, At least one public class is required in main file. So, you have to make the class **project_euler6** as **public**.

```
public class project_euler6 {
    /*** your code ***/
}
```

Comment: I think that might depend on the JVM.  I would have thought that main must be in a public class, but I just tried it and was able to execute a main method out of a non-public class.  Using Mac OSX & 1.7.0_25.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use editor like eclipse, simply create new project and copy-paste the above code. Code looks correct and should compile and give result.